# Can't See 'TestNG' option in the Preferences of eclipse project on Mac OS 10.10.3

Tags: eclipse, macos, testng

I can't see TestNG in the Preferences of project. I am facing this issue on Mac OS 10.10.3 with latest Eclipse Luna SR2 (4.4.2) and TestNG 6.9.5.
Same thing works perfectly fine on windows machine with same eclipse and testng.

Comment: I tried installing JDK 8 U45 and it worked for me. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I tried installing JDK 8 U45 and it worked for me.
Thanks for your help.